# Issue with SAML response notBeforeDate

Tags: java, security, saml

Getting SAMLException" Current date is before the notBeforeDate" during authentication. The current date and "notBeforeDate" are same for 90% login attempts and it results into the error. What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Unless you share some code we cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: This will be most likely caused by timedrift on IdP/SP servers.
If you have access to these servers, make sure you are properly synchronized with NTP servers/or adjust manually time to proper one.

If you don't, inform IT department, working for IdP side or SP side. Let them know to check server time synchronization.

Error is referring to this part of SAML request:

```
<saml:Subject>
  <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">_ce3d2948b4cf20146dee0a0b3dd6f69b6cf86f62d7</saml:NameID>
  <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2014-07-18T06:21:48Z" Recipient="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685"/>
  </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
```